# Certain step in "Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory" on page 60-61

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

Let $v\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be fixed, and put $\lambda(z)=\left ( z+v+\frac{1}{2} \right )\log\left ( 1+\frac{1}{z+v} \right )-1$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. In [Remmert's book page 60-61](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2956-6), he says
$$
|\lambda(z)|\leq \frac{1}{12}\frac{1}{\cos^2(\phi/2)}\left ( \frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z+1|} \right )
$$
for $z=|z|e^{i\phi}\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. What he did was as follows: He proved that
$$
|\lambda(z)|\leq \frac{1}{\cos^2(\phi/2)}\lambda(|z|),
$$
and then completing it by using the fact that
$$
\lambda(r)\leq \frac{1}{12}\left ( \frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1} \right )
$$
for all $r>0$.

**What my problem is**: I do not see how to complete it, because if I replace $r$ by $|z|$ in the latter expression, we would get,
$$
\lambda(|z|)\leq \frac{1}{12}\left ( \frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z|+1} \right ).
$$
What I want is to make the right hand side to be
$$
\leq \frac{1}{12}\left ( \frac{1}{|z|}-\frac{1}{|z+1|} \right ),
$$
which is not the case ... Is this an error in the book?